# HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() timeout issue

Tags: c#, server, timeout, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I get intermittent timeout issue with getting a response from `HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()`. I thought it was an issue with the server, but the server seems to have sent the response within a minute. I have set timeout to be 20 mins.

`GetResponse()` keeps on waiting and then throws:

> The operation has timed out.

I have also used `GetRequestStream()`, `GetResponse()` in `using` blocks. So, I don't think that could be an issue. The issue seems very sporadic. Any help would be appreciated.

```cs
var request = WebRequest.CreateHttp("http://someurl")
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentLength = data.Length;
request.ContentType = "text/xml; encoding='utf-8'";
request.KeepAlive = false;
request.Timeout = 1200 * 1000;
request.ServicePoint.ConnectionLeaseTimeout = request.Timeout;
request.ServicePoint.MaxIdleTime = request.Timeout;

using (System.IO.Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
}
                    
using (System.Net.WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
{
 using (System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
 {
   var response = reader.ReadToEnd();
 }
}
```

Comment: Please try the code below or try using  .Wait(); function in order to obtain the response timely.

Comment: Hi Mirzan, I am not using Async for this. Thanks

Comment: @user2196407 Did you try to `Flush` and `Close` the RequestStream inside the using block?

Comment: @PeterCsala I believe using does that for you? From the log, it looks like its throwing exception on GetResponse() rather than GetRequestStream(). Thanks

Comment: Quite frankly, I haven't seen the `GetRequestStream` in a using block really frequently. On the other hand I've seen so many times explicitly calling the `Flush` and `Close`.  Did you try to cast the `CreateHttp` to `HttpWebRequest` and the `GetResponse` to `HttpWebResponse`?

Comment: By the way how big data do you want to send over? Maybe you have to increase the `maxRequestLength`.

Comment: @PeterCsala code itself works most of the time. So, it is really intermittent. I can try but i don't think it will make a lot of difference as i have now seen it fail for small data too. - thanks

Comment: If it is intermittent could that mean that the server's response could have an effect on your calling code? For example sometimes the response type is `application/json` other times it is in a different media type. If your `WebRequest` is not prepared for a given media type that could also result in operation time out.

Comment: @PeterCsala When we get the response we don't really care what format it sends data back. There could be other issues though. They said they have sent back response but we don't get it.